# Относительный путь к файлу Visual Studio 13 c#

Tags: c#, winforms, адрес, picturebox

Нужно в pictureBox загрузить картинку по относительной ссылке. Картинка в папке img. Пробовал так: img\gogol.jpg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Загрузить в PictureBox картинку из файла можно так

```
var pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Image = new Bitmap(@"img\gogol.jpg");
```

Полный путь к файлу можно получить так

```
var path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"img\gogol.jpg");
```

Answer (score 4):

Убедитесь, что при работе приложения текущая директория приложения у вас та, в которой находится ваш exe (Можно посмотреть в process explorer в свойствах процесса). Тогда относительный путь может быть указан так: .\img\gogol.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\img\\gogol.jpg";
```